# Add row dynamically to android table after 1 minute

Tags: android, android-layout

xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</TableLayout>
```

Activity sample code:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);

        TableRow trHead = new TableRow(this);
        trHead.setId(10);
        trHead.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        trHead.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        TextView col1Header = new TextView(this);
        col1Header.setText("Time");
        col1Header.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        trHead.addView(col1Header);

        TextView col2Header = new TextView(this);
        col2Header.setText("Company");
        col2Header.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        col2Header.setGravity(Gravity.END);
        trHead.addView(col2Header);

        tl.addView(trHead, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            TextClock clock = new TextClock(this);
            row.addView(clock);

            TextView data = new TextView(this);
            data.setText("dev" + 1);
            data.setGravity(Gravity.END);
            row.addView(data);

            tl.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

`SystemClock.sleep(1000);` does not fulfil my need.

Whole table is appering on UI after 3 seconds. But I want rows to be added after 1 minute on the UI.

Comment: What method contains the code you have given? Remember that Java code must be inside a class and a method. Providing these two lines along with the appropriate curly braces helps us better understand when your code is executed.

Comment: I updated the question. It is under `onCreate()`.

Comment: You should also show the class for completeness

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I updated with appropriate class.

Answer (score 0):

Whole table apper after 3 seconds because SystemClock.sleep receive miliseconds as parameters. (1 minute = 60000 miliseconds).

Another way to do it is using a    Runnable

```
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Add row
        }
    };
```

Call runnable:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(r, 60000);
```

Comment: That's fine. I want each row to appear after 1 minute on the UI _(not whole table after 3 minutes)_.

Comment: You shouldn't add rows at onCreate method, UI is show after this methods finish. take a look at the edit.

Comment: you'll want to make sure to clear that handler's runnable's onPause if you're doing it this way

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sleeping inside of `onCreate()`. This blocks the UI thread so nothing will be rendered until **after** `sleep()` returns. This means that the database will be updated and rendered almost immediately. To perform an actual delay, you need to use concurrency of some type. At the lowest level, you can create a new `Thread` or `Runnable`. At a higher level, you can use `AsyncTask`. There are also even higher level abstractions available, but these two options should get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1;i<=3;i++){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //add row
                    }
                });
            }
        },i*60000);
}
```